# Running python functions from terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I'm trying to figure out how to run my functions from my homework file. I opened up terminal, changed the directory to desktop (where my hw1.py file is), started up python, then typed "import hw1". Then I type in fizzbuzz(15) and it returns this statement:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

My only function I'm trying to run is:

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    if (n % 3) == 0 and (n % 5) == 0:
       return "FizzBuzz"
    elif (n % 3) == 0:
       return "Fizz"
    elif (n % 5) == 0:
       return "Buzz"
```

Comment: Some examples of using import: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm

Answer (score 5):

`import hw1` Then use  `hw1.fizzbuzz(15)`

You can also use:

```
from  hw1 import fizzbuzz
```

so you will have imported `fizzbuzz` into your current namespace and can then call it using  `fizzbuzz(15)`.

[python modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#modules)

`import hw1` just imports the module name not all the functions defined in it so either use `my_module.my_function` or the `from my_module import my_function` syntax.

Comment: No worries, have a peek at the doc examples I linked to, there are nice easily understandable examples.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is about executing a function from a python file (as a [Module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)) inside the [Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) in [Interactive Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode), it's also possible to run a function or module with a one-liner (i.e. not use the interactive interpreter), as documented in [Command line and environment](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html). Amongst others:

> When called with -c command, it executes the Python statement(s) given
>   as command. Here command may contain multiple statements **separated by
>   newlines**. Leading whitespace is significant in Python statements!

While quotation marks for strings etc. need escaping (depending on your environment), I could get the desired output on Windows 10 with Python 3.8 using:

```
python -c "import hw1; print(hw1.fizzbuzz(15))"
FizzBuzz
```

I could not simply [insert a newline on Windows CMD](https://superuser.com/questions/150116/how-can-i-insert-a-new-line-in-a-cmd-exe-command), so this may be limited to [Simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=semicolon):

> A simple statement is comprised within a single logical line. Several
>   simple statements may occur on a single line **separated by semicolons**.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
import hw1
hw1.fizzbuzz(15)
```

Method 2:

```
from hw1 import fizzbuzz
fizzbuzz(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

I include this answer because this question is high in google in relevant search cases. Use case is executing a Python script to execute a function there with system arguments. 
Code example with currency exchange expense calculator

```
# 2000 euro 26.6.2017
# python countCurrencyRate.py 18870.75 18908.76
# Output: Currency exchange expense: 0.00201220185227
#
# For https://money.stackexchange.com/a/20277/1627

import sys

a1 = float( sys.argv[1] )
b1 = float( sys.argv[2] )

def countCurrencyRate(a=a1, b=b1):
   # a google currency rate, b destination currency rate; or reverse
   ave = (a+b)/2
   diff = abs(b-a)
   result = diff/ave
   print("Currency exchange expense: %s" % result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   countCurrencyRate(a1, b1)
```

Python: 2.7.9