# zsh: unknown file attribute: 1

Tags: python, file, attributes, zsh

[I can't call my def root (a, b, c) in my mac!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i7P4.png)

I tried to run the file without the anaconda environment but gave the same error.
If I write a simple code like print("oooo") the file runs but I can't call my function in my terminal and I don't know why.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running python functions from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837063/running-python-functions-from-terminal)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977797/how-to-run-python-function-from-command-line

Comment: You're trying to call a python function from the shell. That doesn't work. When you do `python filename.py` python executes everything in the file and then exits, it doesn't put you into a Python REPL.

Comment: the function is never called.  so nothing will happen...

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: Why is this tagged zsh when you only have Python code?

Comment: What? I am new at programming and I recently switched to VSCode when I used pyzo I could call the function in the shell. How do I call the function in vscode?